# How to export .xml element attributes to another existing .xml?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, attributes, element

I have 2 xml files in each movie directory , one called mymovies.xml the other one is moviename.nfo (both xml files).

What I am trying to do is, to "extract" the  child  attributes: Language, Type, Channels:

```
<AudioTracks>
    <AudioTrack Language="German" Type="DTS-HD Master" Channels="7.1" />
    <AudioTrack Language="German" Type="Dolby Digital" Channels="2.0" />
    <AudioTrack Language="English" Type="DTS-HD Master" Channels="7.1" />
</AudioTracks>
```

and 'import' them into the moviename.nfo in the format:

```
<fileinfo>
    <streamdetails>
        <audio>
            <codec>dtshdmaster</codec>
            <language>ger</language>
            <channels>8</channels>
        </audio>
         <audio>
            <codec>dolbydigital</codec>
            <language>ger</language>
            <channels>2</channels>
        </audio>
        <audio>
            <codec>dtshdmaster</codec>
            <language>eng</language>
            <channels>8</channels>
        </audio>
    </streamdetails>
</fileinfo>
```

moviename.nfo example:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<movie>
  <title>Barry Lyndon</title>
  <originaltitle>Barry Lyndon</originaltitle>
  <sorttitle>Barry Lyndon</sorttitle>
  <set>
  </set>
  <rating>8</rating>
  <year>1975</year>
  <top250>
  </top250>
  <votes>
  </votes> 
  <tagline>
  </tagline>
  <runtime>185</runtime>
  <thumb>
  </thumb>
  <mpaa>Rated PG-13</mpaa>
  <playcount>0</playcount>
  <watched>false</watched>
  <id>tt0072684</id>
  <filenameandpath>
  </filenameandpath>
  <country>Germany</country>
  <trailer>
  </trailer>
  <certification>Germany:FSK ab 12 freigegeben</certification>
  <genre>War</genre>
  <genre>Drama</genre>
  <genre>Romance</genre>
  <studio>Peregrine</studio>
  <credits>Stanley Kubrick, William Makepeace Thackeray</credits>
  <director>Stanley Kubrick</director>
  <createdby>My Movies</createdby>
</movie>
```

expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<movie>
  <title>Barry Lyndon</title>
  <originaltitle>Barry Lyndon</originaltitle>
  <sorttitle>Barry Lyndon</sorttitle>
  <set>
  </set>
  <rating>8</rating>
  <year>1975</year>
  <top250>
  </top250>
  <votes>
  </votes>
  <tagline>
  </tagline>
  <runtime>185</runtime>
  <thumb>
  </thumb>
  <mpaa>Rated PG-13</mpaa>
  <playcount>0</playcount>
  <watched>false</watched>
  <id>tt0072684</id>
  <filenameandpath>
  </filenameandpath>
  <country>Germany</country>
  <trailer>
  </trailer>
  <fileinfo>
    <streamdetails>
      <audio>
          <codec>dtshdmaster</codec>
          <language>ger</language>
          <channels>8</channels>
       </audio>
       <audio>
          <codec>dolbydigital</codec>
          <language>ger</language>
          <channels>2</channels>
      </audio>
      <audio>
          <codec>dtshdmaster</codec>
          <language>eng</language>
          <channels>8</channels>
      </audio>
    </streamdetails>
  </fileinfo>
  <certification>Germany:FSK ab 12 freigegeben</certification>
  <genre>War</genre>
  <genre>Drama</genre>
  <genre>Romance</genre>
  <studio>Peregrine</studio>
  <credits>Stanley Kubrick, William Makepeace Thackeray</credits>
  <director>Stanley Kubrick</director>
  <createdby>My Movies</createdby>
</movie>
```

So far I have:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root_node = ET.parse('mymovies.xml').getroot()

for tag in root_node.findall('AudioTracks/AudioTrack'):

value = tag.attrib['Language']
print(value)

value = tag.attrib['Type']
print (value)

value = tag.attrib ['Channels']

print (value)
```

the output is:

```
English
DTS-HD Master
5.1
English
Dolby Digital
2.0
French
Dolby Digital
5.1
Spanish
Dolby Digital
5.1
Portuguese
Dolby Digital
5.1
```

What I want to know now is:

- How can I import 2 ElementTrees?
- How can I write the specific parsed information into the other file?
- How can I bring the attributes exact on the level and in the form i need?

Comment: Prune your XML samples to the minimum. E.g., the `<actor>...</actor>` elements are irrelevant to your question and their absence will not affect the solutions.

Comment: I did that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you can work with this. I made some assumptions re translating the values (language, codec, channels).

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re


# https://web.archive.org/web/20120301034645/http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm#prettyprint
# in-place prettyprint formatter
def indent(elem, level=0):
    i = "\n" + level * "  "
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + "  "
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for elem in elem:
            indent(elem, level + 1)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = i


pattern = re.compile(r'[^A-Za-z]')

source = '''\
<AudioTracks>
    <AudioTrack Language="German" Type="DTS-HD Master" Channels="7.1" />
    <AudioTrack Language="German" Type="Dolby Digital" Channels="2.0" />
    <AudioTrack Language="English" Type="DTS-HD Master" Channels="7.1" />
</AudioTracks>
'''

template = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<movie>
  <title>Barry Lyndon</title>
  <originaltitle>Barry Lyndon</originaltitle>
  <sorttitle>Barry Lyndon</sorttitle>
  <set>
  </set>
  <rating>8</rating>
  <year>1975</year>
  <top250>
  </top250>
  <votes>
  </votes> 
  <tagline>
  </tagline>
  <runtime>185</runtime>
  <thumb>
  </thumb>
  <mpaa>Rated PG-13</mpaa>
  <playcount>0</playcount>
  <watched>false</watched>
  <id>tt0072684</id>
  <filenameandpath>
  </filenameandpath>
  <country>Germany</country>
  <trailer>
  </trailer>
  <certification>Germany:FSK ab 12 freigegeben</certification>
  <genre>War</genre>
  <genre>Drama</genre>
  <genre>Romance</genre>
  <studio>Peregrine</studio>
  <credits>Stanley Kubrick, William Makepeace Thackeray</credits>
  <director>Stanley Kubrick</director>
  <createdby>My Movies</createdby>
</movie>
'''

fileinfo = ET.Element('fileinfo')
e = ET.Element('streamdetails')
fileinfo.append(e)  # wrap in fileinfo

st = ET.fromstring(source)
for at in st.findall('./AudioTrack'):
    codec = pattern.sub('', at.attrib['Type']).lower()
    channels = str(sum(map(int, at.attrib['Channels'].split('.'))))
    language = at.attrib['Language'][:3].lower()
    ET.SubElement(e,
                  'audio',
                  codec=codec,
                  language=language,
                  channels=channels)

out = ET.fromstring(template)
for i, c in enumerate(out):
    if c.tag == 'certification':
        out.insert(i, fileinfo)
        break

indent(out)
print(ET.tostring(out).decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Cool, thank you that works, I changed source and template and it does what I was looking for : ) thanks - the only thing that I put wrong in the desired output is that  the streamdetails element has to be nested into a <fileinfo> </fileinfo). I thought it would be easy to change that just with a Element and a subelement I am trying to add, but I am too stupid to solve that (I am a bloody beginner with programming)

Comment: See edited answer. Oh, and you may want to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.

Comment: ...I accepted it! Thank you very much for your help, I learned a lot, god bless you!